# How to link mach-o format object files on linux?

Tags: linux, linker, ld, mach-o

I have been attempting to link a MACHO formatted object file on Linux, but I have failed miserably. So far, I have created the object file by running:

```sh
nasm -fmacho -o machoh.o hello.o
```

I have tried linking using:

```sh
 clang --target=x86_64-apple-darwin machoh.o
```

but that failed. I have attempted using GCC, LD, and other linkers but I have still failed miserably. Are there any ideas on how I could solve my problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The most accessible solution would be `lld`, the LLVM linker.

1. lld does not ship with clang, but is a separate package.

   ```
   sudo apt install lld
   ```

   If you installed a version of clang that isn't the default (e.g. `clang-12` explicitly), then you should use the same version for lld (i.e. `lld-12`).
2. Get a MacOS SDK from somewhere. [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/alexey-lysiuk/macos-sdk) archives them.

   If you're uncomfortable using the above, the "legitimate" way of obtaining it without a Mac would be:

   1. Create an Apple ID
   2. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
   3. Download the "Command Line Tools for Xcode <version>"
   4. Mount or extract the dmg
   5. Extract the XAR package
   6. For each ".pkg" folder inside, run `pbzx <Payload | cpio -i`
   7. Find the `Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` inside.
3. Feed both of the above to clang:

   ```
   clang --target=x86_64-apple-darwin -fuse-ld=lld --sysroot=path/to/MacOSX.sdk machoh.o
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried linking using: `clang --target=x86_64-apple-darwin machoh.o`
> but that failed.

Failed *how*? Details matter.

Anyway, there are 3 commonly used linkers on Linux: BFD-ld, Gold, and (newest) LLD.

Of these, Gold is an ELF-only linker, and will not work for Mach-O.

BFD-ld is only configured to support a few emulations (use `ld --help` to see which ones) in my distribution. BFD does appear to support Mach-O, so it's probably possible to build a Linux BFD-ld cross-linker with such support.

LLD should support Mach-O out of the box, but you are probably not using LLD.

So your first step should be to figure out which linker `clang --target=x86_64-apple-darwin ...` uses, and then make it use the one which does support Mach-O.